# In Project Euler 47, why is 2^2 considered a prime number distinct from 2?

Tags: primes

How would I get my code to reflect that? Should I just have it consider the number 4 to be prime?

[Project Euler: Problem 47](http://projecteuler.net/problem=47)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, it belongs on the Project Euler Forum.

Answer (score 8):

> The first three consecutive numbers to have three distinct prime factors are:
>
> 644 = 2² × 7 × 23
> 645 = 3 × 5 × 43
> 646 = 2 × 17 × 19.

If you factorize 644 you get 2 × 2 × 7 × 23. 644 has four prime factors, but three *distinct* prime factors.

Comment: I thought it required the prime factors to only appear once among all three consecutive numbers. 644 and 646 both have 2 among their distinct prime factors.
 
What I mean is, why is 2^2 considered prime? If it is, why not 2^3 and 2^5, etc.?

Comment: @user2493615 2² = 4 is not prime. 2 is prime, and it is a factor of 644 twice, as in you can divide 644 by 2 two times. The prime factors of 644 are 2, 2, 7, and 23. The problem is asking you not to count the duplicate "2"s.

Answer (score 2):

The problem statement is not requiring all 9 prime factors to be distinct, but only that each consecutive number have three distinct prime factors.